# What does "per-interactive-shell" mean?

Tags: bash, man

By typing `man bash`, we can see

```
FILES
       /bin/bash
              The bash executable
       /etc/profile
              The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
       /etc/bash.bashrc
              The systemwide per-interactive-shell startup file
       /etc/bash.bash.logout
              The systemwide login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
       ~/.bash_profile
              The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
       ~/.bashrc
              The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
       ~/.bash_logout
              The individual login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
       ~/.inputrc
              Individual readline initialization file
```

What does "per-interactive-shell" means? Especially, what does "per" mean here? Does "per" mean "each" here? Each interactive shell? Or does it mean something else?

Does "the individual per-interactive-shell startup file" mean "the individual startup file for each interactive shell"?

Comment: it means every interactive shell reads those files once. `per-interactive-shell` means the same thing as `once-per-interactive-shell`.

Comment: Note that `info bash` (unlike `man bash`) does not use this wording and, in chapter "Bash Features" > "Bash startup files", gives a reasonably exhaustive explanation of how startup files are used and the relationships among them. (The `info` documentation for GNU projects is usually more detailed than the `man` equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bashrc` files are used for initialising each individual interactive shell.

I'm a bit uncertain why the "per-" prefix is actually needed here, seeing as the exact same situation is true for login shells as well (albeit with regards to other files).  Also, a non-interactive shell would use whatever file `$BASH_ENV` holds the pathname of, or to put it in other words "`$BASH_ENV` is the per-noninteractive-shell startup file" if you will.

It may be an attempt at emphasising (for whatever reason) that the files are actually sourced for *each* interactive shell.

The wording was introduced in release 2.0 of `bash` (I believe).

Comment: Maybe, but still seems to be weird.

Comment: @Victor I'd agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here. First the easy one:

“individual” is just another word for “personal”, meaning (in this case) file from your user-account’s home directory. Note in fact the `~/` prefix to all individual/personal files.

On desktop systems like your computer at home you usually have only one user account, but on server computers there can be several accounts registered, and each one has its own home directory and therefore its own personal/individual `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, etc.

---

Now the hard one, and to try and explain this I need a small preface:

Bash differentiates between “*login*” interactive-shells and "*other*" interactive-shells. (I have no experience about other programs like `zsh` or `ksh` but I suppose they do too).

For example, on Linux systems a *login* shell is typically only the very first one that it’s started after you have entered (correctly) your username and password either from *textual console* or from a network connection such as ssh.

On the contrary, “*other*” interactive-shells are typically the ones started by a graphic desktop when you click the icon of the terminal emulator application.

“*Other*” (ie non-login) interactive-shells are also when you subsequently invoke nested interactive-shells even from a *login* one.

A practical example of this latter case. Suppose you are at the prompt of the first shell after having authenticated yourself (ie *logged in*) to a remote computer via ssh: that’s the *login* interactive-shell; but if you then type `bash` and press Return you start a new *other* interactive-shell. You can nest them as many as you like. Only, you need to type `exit` (or Control-D) for each of them in order to unwind the stack of nested interactive-shells you started.

Bash’s documentation there tells you which files are automatically executed on startup of *login* shells and which other files on startup of *other* shells. There are also a couple of files that are automatically run only when you quit *login* shells, but not when you quit *other* shells.